# Getting nil managedObjectContext in CoreData with Swift working from a Library

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm developing a library for iOS using Swift 5, and I want this library to use CoreData independent of the application which consumes that library and this is what I've done so far:

1. Created the entities with their respective data types
2. Created the `.xcdatamodeld` file, which contains the entities
3. Created a `CoreDataManager` which looks like this:

```swift
// MARK: - CoreDataManager
final class CoreDataManager {
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private static let defaultObject = NSManagedObject.init()
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Audit")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
}
```

And the trouble is I'm trying to get the context by:

```
let coreDataManager = CoreDataManager.shared
let context = coreDataManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

and `context` is returning `nil`

please help

Comment: Have you done any research into this? There are some articles online (and questions here) that describes what steps you need to take to do this.

Comment: I have read many articles and stack overflow questions but most of them says that I need to get the context from the AppDelegate which doesn't make sense for me because I'm working on a library which doesn't have AppDelegate.

Comment: Well then you have read the wrong kind of articles I guess, google "swift core data model in package" and you should find some helpful articles and SO questions

Comment: Thank's @JoakimDanielson I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved it**, and apparently the trouble was that the ios application where I wanted to use my library wasn't finding the `.xcdatamodeld` file which resulted in a useless `NSPersistentContainer` object, which also meant that  `let context = persistentContainer.viewContext`  was `nil`.

In order to avoid this kind of troubles in the future, I'll left a list of important considerations when working with CoreData and swift libraries.

### Key things to consider

1. Make sure the app that is consuming your library knows exactly where
   to look for it. Might want to take a look at [this article for details](https://medium.com/@starecho/something-you-may-need-to-do-when-integrating-core-data-into-your-cocoapods-library-e8e8fad409b8).
2. If you are working with cocoapods for distributing your library, make sure to add the following to your .podspec:
   `s.resources = "path/to/model.xcdatamodeld"`
   This will produce a folder named "Resources" in your Pods target:

[image]

3. Make sure your model file name matches the `NSPersistentContainer` name.
4. **(NOT SURE ABOUT THIS)** I changed the class definition of my NSManagedObjects from

```swift
class Audit: NSManagedObject {}
```

to

```swift
public class Audit: NSManagedObject {}
```

And even when I'm not sure if that makes sense, It could work for you.

Finally I'll leave the code that worked for me

```swift
// MARK: - CoreDataManager
final class CoreDataManager {
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private static let defaultObject = NSManagedObject.init()
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer? = {
        let modelURL = Bundle(for: Audit.self).url(forResource: "Audit", withExtension: "momd")
        
        guard let model = modelURL.flatMap(NSManagedObjectModel.init) else {
            print("Fail to load the trigger model!")
            return nil
        }
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Audit", managedObjectModel: model)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        return container
    }()
}
```

And to get the context outside

```swift
let coreDataManager = CoreDataManager.shared

guard
    let context = coreDataManager.persistentContainer?.viewContext
else {
    print("Nil context case")
    return
}
```

Hope you guys find it helpful!!

Comment: Regarding point 4, you need this if you want to access the class from outside of your library

Comment: Very helpful answer. Your number 3 point worked for me. Somehow the "let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name:" had the wrong value. I changed it manually to my entity's name and that was it! Thank you :)